# Even when using antMatchers.permitAll for the login url, get the error MalformedJwtException

Tags: java, spring, http

I am creating an application with JWT token in spring and angular. When the token is present in the localstorage, the application functions fine. But when using the logging screen, the spring gives me the following error eventhough I have mentioned Spring to permit all requests for the login url. Can someone helped me understand why this happens? No matter what I do Spring checks for the token in the login request. [I am using an httpInterceptor in the angular frontend, so for the logging request, the header is as `Bearer null`]. Is it the reason for the error?

error

> io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0

SecurityConfig

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().disable();
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate")
            .permitAll().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/authenticate")
public String generateToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
    try {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword())
        );
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception("invalid username/password");
    }
    return jwtUtil.generateToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
}
```

JwtRequestFilter

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    String username = null;
    String jwt = null;

    if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
        username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
    }

    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

HttpInterceptor

```
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{

constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

intercept(req, next){
  let authService = this.injector.get(JwtClientService)
  let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer '+authService.getToken()
    }
  });
  return next.handle(tokenizedReq);
}
```

error stack trace

```
io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:235) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.ims.inventoryManagementSystem.util.JwtUtil.extractAllClaims(JwtUtil.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
at com.ims.inventoryManagementSystem.util.JwtUtil.extractClaim(JwtUtil.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
at com.ims.inventoryManagementSystem.util.JwtUtil.extractUsername(JwtUtil.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
at com.ims.inventoryManagementSystem.filters.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

Login Function (Front end - Angular)

```
checkLogin(){
this.service.generateToken(this.credentials).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    if(response != null){
      this.message = "Login Successfull"
      localStorage.setItem("token",response);
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
},
(error) => {
    this.message = "Invalid Credentials!";
});
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the class of `jwtRequestFilter` without sensitive information?

Comment: @libanbn I added the filter code in the question. Thank you

Comment: It seems to me that something went wrong when creating the JWT token and it concatenated `Bearer` with `null`. Can you also provide the error stack trace and show us how your application creates the token? Hide the secret keys and etc.

Comment: @libanbn yes, you are correct! Since at the time of the login, there is no token saved in the browser. So when creating the header, it will concatenate `Bearer` with a `null` . I have added the interceptor to the question. My problem is, when we add `permitAll` to the `/authenticate` , does spring still take it through the filter?

Comment: Yes, the requests on `/authenticate` goes through the filter. What you can do is not send the `Authorization` header to client  when the JWT token is `null` and stop the client saving `null` tokens received from server.

Comment: @libanbn That is the section where I am confused. Please correct me if my thought pattern is wrong. To begin the application, the client should make a call to the backend and get a token. So for that, the login function should call the `/authenticate` function in the backend. And if the login is valid, a token is send and saved in the localstorage. So at the beginning, to call the `/authenticate` function, the login function doesn't have a token. Thus it will call the `/authenticate` function with a header of `Bearer null`. Is there is a way to avoid it?I have added my logging function as well

Comment: You are correct. The issue occurs because the filter is triggered before the request reaches the function for `/authenticate`. Inside the filter, the JWT token is extracted, but since the token from client is `null`, and the filter tries to parse that `null` token, you get that exception you posed. To prevent the request going through the filter when calling `/authenticate`, you can define what URL's can trigger the filter using `@WebFilter` on your `JwtRequestFilter` class. Here is an easy example: https://www.surasint.com/spring-boot-filter-urlpattern/

Comment: thank you so much for this answer! Its a solution too. Like you said I made the frontend not attach a header if the token is null and it worked. :-)